# why can't you execute assert_eq! with structs that do not derive Debug?

Tags: rust

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Anything {
    value: u32,
}

impl Anything {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Anything { value: 42 }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_assert_eq_on_custom_struct() {
    assert_eq!(Anything::new(), Anything::new()); // error[E0277]: `Anything` doesn't implement `Debug`

    assert!(Anything::new() == Anything::new()); // All fine 
}
```

Looking in the implementation of `assert_eq!`, I see that it calls `panicking::assert_failed` and sure enough, this function requires its "left" and "right" parameters to derive `Debug`.

I guess it must be helpful in some cases, but I find it a bit strange that values should derive `Debug` to be compared with `assert_eq!`.

Is this all normal and we should use `assert!(a == b)` instead?

Comment: I know nothing about Rust internals, but it doesn't seem strange to me. Surely, if you've asserted that 2 values are equal and they end up not being, you want to be told what the values actually were? And obviously you need `Debug` for that.

Comment: Rust doesn't let a function behave differently based on whether or not a trait is implemented. See [Parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity) for the reasons why. But further than that, basically every Rust type is already `Debug`, and 99% of yours should be as well. Perhaps if you explained why you're using non-`Debug` types in user-facing code, we could help you get a `Debug` impl for those types, because there's really not very many compelling reasons *not* to implement this trait.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'll dig into your first point about Parametricity. Seems logical to me now that you mention it. +1 -- To be fair, it's not that I did not want to derive Debug. I just figured I should avoid deriving anything without thinking about it, and the particular things I was testing out of curiosity did not really require Debug. But I was about to read about the importance of deriving Debug. I am still relatively inexperienced in Rust.

Comment: @RomainVincent It's a fair instinct. There are some traits that might warrant caution (`Default` is often derive-able but only sometimes desired, for instance, and `Clone` can be undesired if you're implementing a resource handle). `Debug` is pretty much free though, and some other derive-able traits get it right 99% of the time (the default `Eq` and `Ord` are almost always what you would want anyway, so it generally makes sense to take those). I totally respect not blindly deriving, but `Debug` is one of the harmless ones that you should probably just derive everywhere.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo While I agree, I would not that sometimes you want a custom, not derived `Debug` for better output.

Comment: Seems like assert! may have been added later, and contains more logic through procedural macros than the assert_eq! implementation. See https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2011-generic-assert.html

Answer (score 0):

`assert!` will just panic when the expression passed does not computes to true.

But if you look at the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html) for `assert_eq!` it states `On panic, this macro will print the values of the expressions with their debug representations.` And to print the debug representation, debug is needed to be derived.